# Error while trying to perform skimage.equalize_hist over a masked array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-image

I have an image represented as a numpy masked array. The image consists of a foreground and a background, I'm not interested in the background so I masked it away. It's an image with poor contrast, and I'd like to increase the contrast in the foreground using `skimage.exposure.equalize_hist`

I noticed the equalize_hist function takes a named parameter `mask`, to ignore the unmasked data.

My code looks like this

```
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure as ske

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# doesn't really exist
from proprietary import openImage, findForeground

imagePath = "...." # path to the image file
# image format is proprietary, so we have a custom function open it for us
# it returns a regular numpy uint16 2d array
# print(type(img), img.dtype, img.shape) shows
# `
# <class 'numpy.ndarray'> float64 (2688, 1151)
# `
img = openImage(imagePath)
foreground = findForeground(img) # this function sets all background pixels to white

# 65535 == white for a uint16 array
masked_img = np.ma.masked_where(foreground==65535, foreground)

# plotting this `masked_img` using plt.imshow works perfectly, the background is completely white
# and the foreground is shown as it is supposed to

# this goes wrong
mask = np.ma.getmask(masked_img)
equalized = ske.equalize_hist(masked_img, mask=mask)
```

The `ske.equalize_hist` call generates this error, and I'm unsure why.

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-e2b4f8e60ef9> in <module>()
     37         print(type(mask))
     38         print(mask)
---> 39         equalized = ske.equalize_hist(fg, mask=mask)
     40         plt.imshow(equalized, cmap=cmap)
     41         plt.set_title("Equalized histogram with colormap {cmap}".format(cmap=cmap))

C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\exposure\exposure.py in equalize_hist(image, nbins, mask)
    165         cdf, bin_centers = cumulative_distribution(image[mask], nbins)
    166     else:
--> 167         cdf, bin_centers = cumulative_distribution(image, nbins)
    168     out = np.interp(image.flat, bin_centers, cdf)
    169     return out.reshape(image.shape)

C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\exposure\exposure.py in cumulative_distribution(image, nbins)
    125     True
    126     """
--> 127     hist, bin_centers = histogram(image, nbins)
    128     img_cdf = hist.cumsum()
    129     img_cdf = img_cdf / float(img_cdf[-1])

C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\exposure\exposure.py in histogram(image, nbins)
     86         return hist[idx:], bin_centers[idx:]
     87     else:
---> 88         hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(image.flat, bins=nbins)
     89         bin_centers = (bin_edges[:-1] + bin_edges[1:]) / 2.
     90         return hist, bin_centers

C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in histogram(a, bins, range, normed, weights, density)
    495             mn, mx = 0.0, 1.0
    496         else:
--> 497             mn, mx = a.min() + 0.0, a.max() + 0.0
    498     else:
    499         mn, mx = [mi + 0.0 for mi in range]

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'MaskedIterator' and 'float'
```

Anyone have any idea why this happens? I'm at a loss.

Comment: As a general rule `numpy` and third party code does not handle masked arrays in any special way.  They just use the full `data` attribute.  You have to use `np.ma...` functions or functions that delegate to `ma` methods.  But have you tried `equalize_hist(masked_img.data, mask=mask)`?

Comment: Also, `foreground=65535` should probably be `foreground==65535`

Comment: @MadPhysicist True, I had a double equals in my original code, but not here. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @hpaulij suggests, stay away from masked arrays as much as you can when you are planning on passing the data around. Given the usage you show here, there is no particular reason not to just maintain a separate mask:

```
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure as ske

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# doesn't really exist
from proprietary import openImage, findForeground

imagePath = "...." # path to the image file
# image format is proprietary, so we have a custom function open it for us
# it returns a regular numpy uint16 2d array
# print(type(img), img.dtype, img.shape) shows
# `
# <class 'numpy.ndarray'> float64 (2688, 1151)
# `
img = openImage(imagePath)
foreground = findForeground(img) # this function sets all background pixels to white

# 65535 == white for a uint16 array
mask = (foreground != 65536)

# plotting this `masked_img` using plt.imshow works perfectly, the background is completely white
# and the foreground is shown as it is supposed to

# foreground should work as well as the original img here
equalized = ske.equalize_hist(img, mask=mask)
```

Keep in mind also that the mask for masked arrays has the opposite sense of what [`equalize_hist`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.exposure.html#skimage.exposure.equalize_hist) is expecting. [`numpy.ma.MaskedArray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.baseclass.html#numpy.ma.MaskedArray) sets [*invalid* elements](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.baseclass.html#numpy.ma.MaskedArray.mask) to `True`, while equalize_hist expects the *valid* elements to be `True`.

It may be beneficial to have `proprietary.findForeground` just return a mask for you, instead of messing with the original image. This would have the advantage of not tying the masked value to the `dtype` of the image, and not running into issues with saturated foreground pixels. If you have the ability to do this, your code would look something like:

```
mask = findForeground(img) # Now returns a boolean array of the correct size
...
equalized = ske.equalize_hist(img, mask=mask)
```

As you can see, this will eliminate step from your process.